# Vim: Increase document traversal speed

Tags: vim

I sometimes find document traversal to be too slow in Vim when using `h, j, k, l`.
Is there a way to temporally increase the number of lines / characters that these keys move the cursor? (I.e. instead of moving `1j`, pressing `j` will move `3j`)

Edit:
Solution:

```
:map <F8> :noremap j 3j <CR>
:map <S-F8> :noremap j j <CR>
```

I wanted something like this so that I can easily browse longer bodies of code that am not necessarily familiar it. This approach allows me to easily toggle between "browsing" mode and "coding" mode.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While possible (use `:noremap j 3j` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and `:noremap j j` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restore), it may not be useful for very long to change the behaviour of these keys.

There are many ways to navigate in Vim. Of course you can advance by full screens using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

You can, as you alluded to, enter a number of moves before executing the navigation.

You can also go directly to a specific line using <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, for example.

If you see the text to which you want to navigate, use <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>?</kbd> followed by the text.

For <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd>, you can navigate word boundaries more quickly with <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, and <kbd>e</kbd>, and contiguous non-whitespace with <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, and <kbd>E</kbd>.

Answer (score 14):

Try Ctrl+D/Ctrl+U and Ctrl+F/B (Up/Down, Forward/Back respectively).

These will traverse the document much faster than `h,j,k,l`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I came across this a while ago and forgot about it. It'll definitely be helpful for future coding.

Comment: It may be worth noting here that you can set the number of lines scrolled by `C-u` and `C-d` by passing a count the first time (or setting the 'scroll' option).  Any following presses will also use this count without having to pass it again.

Answer (score 5):

What @Bryan Ross have suggested is absolutely right. I want to add just a thing. Use [relativenumber](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27relativenumber%27), it will help you to use `j` and `k` more efficiently.

Comment: Excellent, thanks man. I think what I like most about Vim is that no matter how much I learn there are always other cool features lurking around for me to try.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by Jay is sufficient, I would like to add the following !

There are many different kinds of navigation possible in vim, ( where as the h, j, k, l are just line navigation ). Some more are:

- screen navigation
- spl navigation
- search navigation
- word navigation

Refer this write up to find out the short cut keys to do it: [Essential Vim editor navigation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/8-essential-vim-editor-navigation-fundamentals/)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that helps is to have line numbers turned on (:set number). If you see on the screen where you need to go and see the line number, it's just G.

If you deal with code in blocks, % will move you to a matching brace, parenthesis, etc.

If you deal with files with lots of wacky characters, t, T, f, and F are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try `CTRL + Y` & `CTRL + E` to scroll instead of moving the line
use the `CTRL + B` to scroll to bottom of page and `CTRL + F` to scroll to top of page
use the `H` (Height), `M` (middle), `L` (low) to move the cursor to top, middle and bottom of screen

you can also increase the speed of `CTRL + Y` and other keys as of this answer explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990810/10539792

Answer (score -1):

I know there's so many vim tricks to traversal quickly, but for me is the most comfortable is a mechanical keyboard, with built in repeat rate increase when u hold a button it increase the repeat reat etc for the j or k so the traversal will be quick and smooth too. (So nice!)
But its annoying when u have your vimrc but didnt have your keyboard so not a universal solution.